# IIS: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: asp.net, apache, flash, iis, webserver

I have an SWF file on my website that requires some files from a subdirectory. I am running it on my own home network (port forwarded) not on a server. When I access the website's page with the SWF file on it works perfectly fine.

When others access the page, in their developers tools console window they receive a :

> 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)'

for every file that has been requested by SWF. They can visit the same (SWF requested) URLs on their browser perfectly fine (they exist), it just doesn't actually allow the SWF to require same files, can anyone help?

I am running on IIS web server, these files are on a subdomain (so is the SWF file) but the website with the page they are visting is on the main domain.

Comment: _"When others access the page"_ Where is the link to test issue?

Answer (score 0):

Flash needs a crossdomain.xml file to be able to load files from another domain. Since your page is on the main domain the flash security assumes you are on the the same domain (although the swf is physically on the subdomain). In your case the crossdomain.xml should be in the root folder of your subdomain. This should do the trick (use secure="true" in case you are using https):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE cross-domain-policy SYSTEM
"http://www.adobe.com/xml/dtds/cross-domain-policy.dtd">
<cross-domain-policy>
 <allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
</cross-domain-policy>
```